# Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement'

Tags: jquery

I'm able to fill the form that is inside the external site in the iframe automatically, but I want to load the page already has the event click on submit the form.

I tried as below but this returning error:   **Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement'**

```
 <?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');  ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

    <iframe src="http://example.com/contact/" id="InnerIframe" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>

    <script>

    $(window).on('load', function() {
       $('#InnerIframe').contents().find('submit').trigger( "click" );
    });

    </script>
```

**Console log**

```
Exception: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
    at contents (http://localhost/site/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3197:14)
    at Function.map (http://localhost/site/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:457:13)
    at jQuery.fn.init.jQuery.fn.(anonymous function) [as contents] (http://localhost/site/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3201:24)
    at http://localhost/site/:8:22
    at dispatch (http://localhost/site/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:5201:27)
    at elemData.handle (http://localhost/site/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:5009:28)contents @ jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3197map @ jquery-3.1.1.min.js:457jQuery.fn.(anonymous function) @ jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3201(anonymous function) @ (index):8dispatch @ jquery-3.1.1.min.js:5201elemData.handle @ jquery-3.1.1.min.js:5009
util.js:208 Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keysPA.j @ util.js:208(anonymous function) @ js?v=3.exp&key&ver=4.6.1:127(anonymous function) @ js?v=3.exp&key&ver=4.6.1:46(anonymous function) @ js?v=3.exp&key&ver=4.6.1:43(anonymous function) @ js?v=3.exp&key&ver=4.6.1:46(anonymous function) @ js?v=3.exp&key&ver=4.6.1:99(anonymous function) @ js?v=3.exp&key&ver=4.6.1:43(anonymous function) @ js?v=3.exp&key&ver=4.6.1:99(anonymous function) @ js?v=3.exp&key&ver=4.6.1:43(anonymous function) @ js?v=3.exp&key&ver=4.6.1:99ic @ js?v=3.exp&key&ver=4.6.1:45hc.Sb @ js?v=3.exp&key&ver=4.6.1:99(anonymous function) @ util.js:1
```

Comment: As the error states, it's a cross-origin error, as you can only access iframes from the same-origin, according to the [same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: @adeneo Thank you, I understand, how can I replace iframes to load external page?

Comment: You can't. There's no way to access other peoples websites through an iframe, that's the point, it's a security "feature".

Comment: @adeneo with XMLHttpRequest I can do?

Answer (score 1):

That's a normal security measure used by all the browsers. You can't access elements or frames that have a different origin, that would be a huge security flaw. Hence, the browser blocks all the scripts that try to do that kind of stuff. To perform any action inside a frame its content must have the same origin.